# How to fit a caption of a figure in the column? [LATEX]

Tags: floats, captions, two-column, sidewaysfigure

I have a double column layout in Latex, but i have a problem withb caption of a figure because text is too long and it overlap on the first column. How to fix it?

i used this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{images/grouped-stacked-barchart-example.PNG}
   \caption{very long description very long description very long description very long description very long description}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please edit your question and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), a complete small test document that others can use to reproduce the issue you describe? Especially the documentclass you use, is of interest.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{very long description very long description very long description very long description very long description}
\end{figure}\end{document}
`